# Inconsistent Jenkins workspace path on slave machines

Tags: jenkins

We have some jobs set up which share a workspace.  The workflow for the various branches is:

- Build a big honking C++ project called `foo`.
- Execute several downstream tests, each of which uses the workspace of `foo`.

We accomplish this by assigning the `Use custom workspace` field of the downstream jobs to the build workspace.

Recently, we took one branch and assigned it to be build on a Jenkins slave machine rather than on the master.  I was surprised to find that on master, the `foo` repository was cloned to `$JENKINS_JOBS_PATH/FOO/workspace/foo_repo` - while on the slave, the repository was cloned to `$JENKINS_JOBS_PATH/FOO/foo_repo`.

Is this by design, or have we somehow configured master and slave inconsistently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of Jenkins put the workspace under the `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/JOB/workspace` directories. After upgrading, this pattern stays with the Jenkins instance. New versions put the workspaces in `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/`.  I suspect the slaves don't need to follow the old pattern (especially if it is a newer slave), so the directories may not be consistent across machines.

You can change the location of the workspaces on the master in Jenkins -> Configure Jenkins -> Advanced.

I think the safe way to handle this... If you are going to use a custom workspace, you should use that for all of your jobs, including the first one that builds the big honking c++ project.

If you did this all in a pipeline, you can run all of this in a single job and have more control over where all the files are, and you have the option of `stash` and `unstash`, but if the files are huge, stash may not be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit 'Use custom workspace' option for each job and instead change master and/or slave workspace paths and use

```
%WORKSPACE%/../foo_repo path
```

or (that equal)

```
./../foo_repo path
```

In that case

```
%WORKSPACE% = [master or slave node workspace]/[job name]
```

and

```
%WORKSPACE%/../ = [master or slave node workspace]
```